# Cannot call object() method on JSONStringer class in Kotlin

Tags: android, json, android-studio, kotlin

I am using the [org.json.JSONStringer](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONStringer) class to generate JSON strings for my Android application.

```kotlin
fun createJSONString(stringer:JSONStringer) {
    stringer.object()
    //write some stuff
    stringer.endObject()
}
```

However, I can't call the [`object()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONStringer#object()) method of this class to create a new JSON Object, since `object` is a kotlin property. Thus, Android studio tells me that constructors are not allowed for objects. What could I do to force Android Studio to use the JSONStringer's `object()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `JSONObject` class instead, example to and from JSONObject:

```
    val jsonStr = "{\"age\":33,\"messages\":[\"msg 1\",\"msg 2\"],\"name\":\"jim\"}"
    val jObj = JSONObject(jsonStr)
    val str = jObj.toString()
```

Since `JSONStringer` is just an implementation of `JSONObject#toString` and `JSONArray#toString`, also usage of this API is discouraged as described in:

[JSONStringer](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONStringer)

> Implements JSONObject#toString and JSONArray#toString. Most application developers should use those methods directly and disregard this API

Here's a good tutorial: [Json parser](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm)

And as alternative you can use JSON serialization / deserialization library like GSON or Jackson

[How to convert Java object to / from JSON (Jackson)](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)

Comment: My pleasure, i use Gson in a lot of company projects but Jackson is very robust i use in my personal projects and if you work with Spring it support Jackson out of the box, only difference is Jackson has lots of feature that may seem overwhelming if you come form GSON, so give them both a try also check out Moshi library

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
stringer.`object`()
```

See [Escaping for Java identifiers that are keywords in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#escaping-for-java-identifiers-that-are-keywords-in-kotlin).